# Stripe with Django - Retrieve product / price from Session

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm integrating Stripe Checkout with my django website. I have 2 products and everytime a PaymentIntent is successful, I want to fetch the Price related (the product that was bought).

I have 2 checkouts, one for each product, and a webhook to listen.

**views.py** - Create a purchase session (exist twice for product 1 & 2)

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_checkout_session_product1(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        domain_url = 'example.com'
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            success_url=domain_url + 'paiement_ok/',
            cancel_url=domain_url + 'paiement_ko/',
            payment_method_types=['card'],  
            line_items=[
            {
              "price" : "price_1...",     <----- What I want to fetch
              "quantity": 1,
            },
        ],
        mode='payment',
        customer_email=request.user.get_username(),
    )
    return JsonResponse({'sessionId': checkout_session['id']})
```

**views.py** - Webhook to trigger a process after a purchase

```
@csrf_exempt
def webhook(request):
    payload = request.body
    sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
            )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    # Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']

        #then I'd want to do something like :
        line_items = stripe.checkout.Session.list_line_items(session.id)
        price = line_items.data.price.id
        if price == product1:
            activate_process_product1(session.customer_email)
        elif price == product2:
            activate_process_product2(session.customer_email)
    
    # Passed signature verification
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

So the webhook works since I get the money.

But I don't get how to fetch the product once the purchase is complete ?

Comment: When exactly do you want to be fetching the product after the purchase is complete? The `checkout.session.completed` event is already triggered after purchase is complete and your pulling the product information there.

Comment: Or is your question how to get the product from the Payment Intent object?

Comment: Thanks karbi, ideally when the Payment intent's status is succeeded i'd like to fetch the product. Unsure how, i suppose it should be done from the Webhook view, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Left an answer below - when the payment intent is successful you should get a `payment_intent.succeeded` event. You can pull out the Payment Intent and use the steps below to get the prices products. Alternatively, you can rely on the fact that `checkout.session.completed` is emitted after payment is successful and work with the Checkout Session directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a Payment Intent that was created from a Checkout Session, you need to go back and retrieve the associated Checkout Session to get price/product information.

1. Get the ID of the Payment Intent.
2. Make a request to list Checkout Sessions [0] while setting `payment_intent` and having `data.line_items` expanded [1]. The call in python should look like this: `sessions = stripe.checkout.Session.list(payment_intent='pi_xxx', expand=['data.line_items'])`
3. If the call was successful and returned a non-empty list of Checkout Sessions, take the first one and check `line_items` for information on the price and product.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list#list_checkout_sessions-payment_intent

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/expand#lists

Comment: Awesome karbi, thanks a lot !! I've found a workaround that I'll post below, that was before I saw your answer which seems way cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

One way I've found to get it from the Session was to use the stripe.checkout.Session.list_line_items method.

```
if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
    session = event['data']['object']
    line_items = stripe.checkout.Session.list_line_items(session.id)
    price_id = line_items.data[0]['price']['id']
```

got me the price id.

Source : [Stripe doc](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/line_items)